# SQL Server Scripting Server Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I generated a Script of a database of size appox. 8GB  using SQL Server's scripting Service. (Schema and Data).

Now When I try to to open the generated Script file(.sql) , I get two different errors randomly.

Sometimes I get

[image]

And sometimes I get

[image]

In no specific order.

It is SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 64 bit , Enterprise Edition. 
Windows 2008 R2 Server SP2 64-bit , Enterprise Edition.

Any Idea what this is and how I can fix this? any suggestions or pointers in the right direction are much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8 GB is a very large SQL file, you won't be able to open such a big file in Management Studio without running into weird problems like those error messages you are seeing.

I suggest you use the `sqlcmd` command line tool to run your 8 GB file.

```
sqlcmd -S <db_servername> -d <db_name> -i <sql_filename.sql> -U <sql_username> –P <sql_password>
```

([sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) is usually located in the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn` for SQL Server 2008 R2)